error regarding color conversion of an image using pillow in python
In the context of converting an image from colored to grey,
from PIL import Image

# Open an image
img = Image.open("secondpython.png")



# Define a 4-tuple matrix for grayscale conversion



# Convert image to grayscale using the matrix

img_gray=img.convert("L")
img_gray.show()

is used to apply grayscale on the image, which works as intended.
However, when attemptting to convert an image to other colors using a tuple:
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("secondpython.png")

red = (0.90, 0.36, 0.18, 0.00,  # Corrected matrix length
           0.11, 0.72, 0.07, 0.00,
           0.02, 0.12, 0.95, 0.00)
img_edited = img.convert("RGB", red)

img_colored = img.convert("RGB", red)
img_colored.show()

AN error appears, stating:
File "c:\Users\username\OneDrive\New folder (4)\finaltest.py", line 9, in 
img_edited = img.convert("RGB", red)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 960, in convert
im = self.im.convert_matrix(mode, matrix)
ValueError: image has wrong mode
I am greatly confused as i followed the nessacary layout.
Help is greatly apreciated.

Please don't create duplicate questions. Instead, edit your original post and update its contents. Also ensure that the debug output is properly formatted too.
